# trying to understand a Python Unicode exception

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, python-unicode

I have a string object of unspecified type.  It will match types.StringTypes, but could be a type.StringType or type.UnicodeType - I'm not sure what I'll receive.  I can't necessarily control what comes in.

My issue occurs when I have a non-ascii character in a string type , and pass the call into misaka ( which is a sundown parser )

in this example, we're dealing with unichr(8250) / u'\u203a' , which caused this a handful of times in my error logs...

```
a = "›"
b = u"›"

print type(a) # <type 'str'>
print type(b) # <type 'unicode'>

print a # fine
print b # fine

import misaka

markdown_renderer = misaka.HtmlRenderer()
renderer = misaka.Markdown( markdown_renderer )

try:
    print renderer.render( a )
    #this will fail
    print "GOOD a"
except:
    print "FAILED a"

try:
    print renderer.render( b )
    #this will pass
    print "GOOD b"
except:
    print "FAILED b"
```

I can't figure out how to turn the "a" object into something that misaka won't have issues with.  'b' always works.  can anyone offer a suggestion ?

Comment: Maybe Misaka is designed to work with unicode strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `str` always fails but a `unicode` always succeeds, you presumably need to decode your `str` object before passing it in. The trick is knowing the encoding: if you do, you can just do (for example) `a.decode('utf-8')`. But if you don't know, then I understand the [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) package does a reasonable job of guessing: but note that guessing is all you can do.

Comment: Thanks.  `chardet` is exactly what I need.  I don't know the charset , so couldn't provide one to `unicode(text,charset)`.  you saved the day!